# iOS Core Animation fails after segue / view transition

Tags: ios5, core-animation, segue

I have a basic animation, simply rotating an image, I'm using Core Animation.  In the viewWillAppear method I create the animation:

```
gearRotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
gearRotate.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
gearRotate.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
gearRotate.duration = 2;
gearRotate.fromValue = 0;
gearRotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(360*M_PI)/180];
[gearButton.imageView.layer addAnimation:gearRotate forKey:@"transform.rotation"];


[self stopGear];
```

I'm calling stopGear initially to pause the animation.  I did have this code in viewDidLoad to start with.  Anyway, when the animation is called it works fine:

```
-(void)startGear {
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [gearButton.imageView.layer timeOffset];
gearButton.imageView.layer.speed = 1.0;
gearButton.imageView.layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
gearButton.imageView.layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [gearButton.imageView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
gearButton.imageView.layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
```

}

And this pause method works fine too:

```
-(void)stopGear {
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [gearButton.imageView.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
gearButton.imageView.layer.speed = 0.0;
gearButton.imageView.layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
```

}

However, this all fails if I segue to another view then back to the main view.  The app runs fine but the animation will never run if I've been to another view.

This is why I initially moved this code to viewWillAppear, thinking I needed to re-create my animation, but no beans.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: When does `startGear` run when you return?

Comment: startGear is called each time the user presses a button.  I call [self startGear] and [self lowerGUI] - the lowerGUI method works fine (it's a UIView animation) but the CA doesn't run.

Comment: If you check the `animationKeys` of the layer before you start it, is your gear rotation on the layer?

Comment: You mean something like:  if (gearRotate == [[gearButton.imageView layer] animationForKey:@"transform.rotation"])...  I tried that, no difference. :/

Comment: Actually I only meant `if ([[gearButton.imageView layer] animationForKey:@"transform.rotation"]) { // there is a animation to be modified}` In what order does the above code run when you go back to the view?

Comment: OK.  When we get back to the main view, on viewWillAppear I create, assign then pause the animation.  In the startGear function I added the check as you described above.  It runs the first time, but again not after I've been in another view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13048/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-mrempty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved this by re-thinking how animations work.  I'm now simply creating the animation each time I want it to run:

```
-(void)startGear {
    gearRotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    gearRotate.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    gearRotate.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    gearRotate.duration = 2;
    gearRotate.fromValue = 0;
    gearRotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(360*M_PI)/180];
    [[gearButton.imageView layer] addAnimation:gearRotate forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

}

And when I want to pause it, I simply remove it:

```
-(void)stopGear {
    [[gearButton.imageView layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"transform.rotation"];
```

}

I'm not sure currently if this is the Apple preferred method, but it works solidly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gearRotate.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;` you could have used the following approach in order to keep your animation running after performing a segue to another view controller:

```
-(void)startGear {
    [[gearButton.imageView layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"transform.rotation"];
    gearRotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    gearRotate.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    gearRotate.duration = 2;
    gearRotate.fromValue = 0;
    gearRotate.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(360*M_PI)/180];
    [[gearButton.imageView layer] addAnimation:gearRotate forKey:@"transform.rotation"];
    [self performSelector:@selector(startGear) withObject:nil afterDelay:gearRotate.duration];
}
```